# Angular on doubleclick Div append to div

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to find a way to add something inside a div when i double click it.

So I have a div:

```
<div>Double click here</div>
```

What I need to do with Angular is when I doubleclick on a div I need the code to add "something" to the else of the div.

For example...

Before I doubleclick I have:

```
<div>Double click here</div>
```

and after I doubleclick I need to have:

```
<div something>Double click here</div>
```

How can I do this in Angular 2 / 4 ?

Comment: what is 'add "something" to the else of the div' ?

Comment: Do you want to add attribute on double click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="show" (dblcick)="show=!show">You see the first div</div>
<div *ngIf="!show" (dblclick)="show=!show">You see the second div</div>
```

or if you are trying to add an attribute on a div:

**HTML**

```
<div [attr.something]="show ? true : null" (dblclick)="show=!show">Double click me to see the change</div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aNB2HT9qU5TwARqTHsEf?p=preview)

Comment: Thats not what the OP is looking for I guess

Comment: I think he is looking to add an attribute to the same div

Comment: This way we always have `something` attribute with `''` or ` : Hey !` value

Comment: @yurzui, yes because I wanted to show that it works... but I understand you, will think, this is a little chalanging or it's just me :( ?

Comment: I want to motivate you:) But @max2020 should provide more information about his problem

Comment: Oh, thank you :) I love challanges, specially from you @yurzui, your posts are always very precise and neat :)

Comment: @yurzui, I did an update of the plunker, is it correct?

Comment: Thanks. It looks great.`[attr.something]="show ? '' : null"` seems that what he is expecting